# Method does not override father's method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have written the following program in `C++`:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    void foo() { cout << "A::foo" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {} 
    void foo() override { cout << "B::foo" << endl; } 
};
```

For some reason `B::foo()` does not override the `A::foo()`:

> error: ‘void B::foo()’ marked ‘override’, but does not override

Also if I remove the `override` keyword and run:

```
int main()
{
    A* a = new B();
    a->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

It prints: `A::foo`. Why it does not override?

Comment: Plus one for using `override` to be able to spot errors like this! `A::foo()` is not virtual, so `overide` does not overide. Make `A`'s `foo`: virtual, like: `virtual  void foo() { cout << "A::foo" << endl; }`